# Can a pixie levitate on bootlaces carried by a spirit of salzacas?

Tags: dnd-4e, pixie

Given:

A pixie, tiny creature weighing 1-4 pounds. Presuming the sum total of gear weight is less than 10 pounds. A nice thin platter, or a net of bootlaces, made out of a light substance of the player's choice that is strong enough to carry the pixie. The [Prison of Salzacas](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2096)       magic item or equivalent cantrip.

Scenario:

The pixie summons the spirit, stands upon the platter, and commands the spirit to bear the platter. As a conjuration, I believe the spirit ignores altitude in its movement, being able to move in any direction just like the spirit companion of a shaman can. If so, is this a slow, if functional way to levitate around the battlefield?

Comment: The (at will) Air Spirit Primal Attunement for the Sentinal Druid is a nice replacement for the Prison :)

Comment: The link to the Prison of Salzacas requires a non-free subscription. Is [this](http://www.obsidianportal.com/campaigns/sojourn-green/items/prison-of-salzacas) the same item?

Comment: yes. think mage hand as item

Comment: Everytime I read this question, it sounds like "how many angels fit on the head of a pin"?

Comment: But slightly more practical. I've got 2 pixies in my current game and the next real PC I make will most likely be one :)

Comment: @SimonWithers - Please take a look at [my question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/23012/1658) about your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The plate is an object, fair game for the prison the carry. There is no prohibition to prevent the pixie from landing on the object, thus it would then have a moving platter that it can levitate on.

The catch here is making the platter big enough and light enough. if needs to be 2.5x2.5 for the pixie not to have to squeeze, a size that will make enormously heavy (30" is huge). The net idea may work, although again it would need to be large enough to hold without squeezing and light enough that it doesn't break the other requirements here. If the pixie does not care about squeezing then this is a useful option, if they do then its less so.

Answer (score 4):

From the DDI glossary entry for conjuration:

> Occupies No Squares: The conjuration occupies no squares. The conjuration does not need to be supported by a solid surface, so it can float in the air.

The Shaman spirit companion does not have any declaration that explicitly allows it to ignore altitude, so since it can, it must do so by virtue of "it can float in the air" ... which would applies to all conjurations, including the spirit conjured from the Prison of Salzacas.

Comment: So does this allow it to carry the pixie?

Comment: I see no reason that it wouldn't...