# How can a Sentinel Druid get the Air Spirit Primal Attunement?

Tags: dnd-4e

In a comment on [Can a pixie levitate on bootlaces carried by a spirit of salzacas?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13172/1658), [Simon Withers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/428/simon-withers) said

> The (at will) Air Spirit Primal Attunement for the Sentinal Druid is a nice replacement for the Prison :)

As fas as I can see, Primal Attunements are `Druid Utility` powers available only to *Protector Druids*, so can't just be swapped in. What am I missing? Is it in fact possible for a Sentinel Druid to gain access to these, or was Simon having a laugh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a case of mistaken identity. That power is *only* available to the Protector Druid and is not a feature of the Sentinel druid.

Other types of Druids do not have access to the attunement utility powers as normal level up powers because in order to take a power at a level the power has to have a level and these utility powers do not have levels assigned to them (That rule is on the RC p87 under retraining).

There does not seem to be a feat that allows either a druid or any other class access to the Protector's class features through multiclass or power swaps so it really does look like it's locked to the Protector.